# Beta(Market model regression) value company wise with moving window

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, regression

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
company_name  co_stkdate  dailyreturns  marketreturn
A             01-01-2000  5.67          4.54
A             02-01-2000  3.43          1.23
A             03-01-2000 -1.01         -0.53
.
.
.
A             30-12-2018  5.65          3.45
A             31-12-2018  2.32          1.32
B             01-01-2000 -2.34         -1.12
B             02-01-2000  1.32          0.34
.
.
.
```

There are hundred such companies. I want to perform OLS regression company-wise with moving window of 1 year.

regression model is

> dailyreturn=alpha+beta*marketreturn

After performing regression. I want to get beta value for each year.

Output should look something like.

```
company_name   year  beta
 A             2000  0.87
 A             2001  0.99
 A             2002  0.76
 A             2003  0.65
.
.
.
```

this is what I have done so far.

```
betas <- dbdf %>% group_by(co_code,company_name) %>% do(model=lm(formula=dailylogrtn~niftyreturns,data=.))
```

This helped me to get one beta value company-wise for 2000-2018. I am not sure how to perform regression analysis with moving windows of 1 year.
Regression analysis should be from 01-01-2000 to 31-12-2000 then new window 01-01-2001 to 31-12-2001 then 01-01-2002 to 31-12-2002 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this on my own. First you need to convert date into year .You just need to replace some terms in group_by().

```
betas <- dbdf %>% group_by(company_name,year) %>% do(model=lm(formula=dailylogrtn~niftyreturns,data=.))
```

model can be converted into dataframe by tiny() function in library(broom)